# Ordering a filter result in Django

Tags: django, search, filter, sql-order-by, django-filters

I made a Search results function in view.py:

```
def search_results(request):   
    book_list = Book.objects.all()    
    book_filter = BookFilter(request.GET, queryset=book_list)
    book_list = book_filter.qs.order_by('title')    
    return render(request, 'catalog/search_results.html', {'filter': book_list})
```

But it seems that the line

```
book_list = book_filter.qs.order_by('title')
```

doesn't have any effect on the result. Could someone help?

The BookFilter class looks like:

```
class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        Cim = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="title",
                                          lookup_expr='icontains',
                                          label="Book's title")        
    
        Author = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="Author__first_name",
                                                      lookup_expr='icontains',
                                                      label="Book's author")  
    
        Status = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="Status",
                                                      lookup_expr='icontains',
                                                      label="Book's status")  
        class Meta:
            model = Book
            fields = '__all__'
```

The html containing the results looks like this:

```
  {% for book in filter.qs %}
       <tr style="background-color:{{ book.BackColor }}">
       <td><a style="color: {{ book.ForeColor }}" href="{{ book.get_absolute_url }}">{{ book.title}}</a></td>
        <td style="color: {{ book.ForeColor }}">{{ book.Author.last_name }} {{ book.Author.first_name }}</td>        
      </tr>
  {% empty %}
      <tr>
        <td style="color: #aeb189" colspan="5">No books</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is `BookFilter` in your code? It may already execute the query when you try to apply `order_by` to the query set.

Answer (score 0):

Use [OrderingFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#orderingfilter). Add `order_by = OrderingFilter(fields=("title",))` to your filter class.